# Proper way hint '->' mutiple return type in python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, pep8

**I was writing a function that can return a string or None.**

so if i wanna hint that with '->',

Is this the valid way of doing it

```
def get_context(arg: str) -> str or None:
     ...
```

> should I use the `str or None` here or theres a better way of hinting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) should be used when something can be one of many types

```
from typing import Union

def get_context(arg: str) -> Union[str, None]:
    ...
```

[`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) can be used when the type is either `None` or something else for convenience

```
from typing import Optional

def get_context(arg: str) -> Optional[str]:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you lain Shelvington for your answer.

Comment: please add the import conditions in your answer

Comment: @omar added some additional info

Comment: Thanks again @Iain Shelvington